# About composition of Holder functions.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, banach-spaces, holder-spaces

Let $f,g$ be Holder continuous functions with respective exponents $\alpha, \beta \in (0,1)$.

More precisely $f \in C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$, $g\in C^{\beta}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$.

I am wondering whether the composition $g \circ f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is Holder of exponent $\min \{\alpha,\beta \}$, i.e, if $g \circ f \in C^{\min\{\alpha,\beta \}}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R})$.

This is claimed on a paper I am reading but I don't know how to prove it. The naive approach would be:

$$
|g(f(x+h))-g(f(x))| \le [g]_{\beta}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^{\beta} \le [g]_{\beta} |h|^{\beta \alpha} [f]^{\beta}_{\alpha}
$$

so we have $g \circ f \in C^{\alpha \beta }(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But $\alpha \beta < \min \{\alpha,\beta\}$, so this is not very helpful.

Any help would be welcome.

Thak you.

Comment: I think that $\alpha\beta$ is optimal. Consider, for example, the functions $f,g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^\alpha$ and $g(x)=x^\beta$. Now the composition $f\circ g$ belongs to $C^{\alpha\beta}$, however, it does not belong to $C^\gamma$ for any $\gamma>\alpha\beta$.

Comment: So true. Thank you. Then it seems the paper is wrong, and I am in trouble :(

Comment: Maybe you just misunderstood something?

Comment: Maybe I can fix the argument, and prove the result without this claim, but at first sight it does not look well. I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomás: that should probably be an answer.

Comment: @juan: it could be a genuine mistake. For classically differentiable functions from the chain rule you see that composition of $C^k$ and $C^n$ functions get you regularity $C^{\min(k,n)}$. I can see someone not paying attention and assuming this also holds for Holder class.

Comment: Finally this claim was not necessary to prove the main result. It appeared in a boothsatrap argument to see regularity, but a minor modification solves the problem and prove the same result. I guess the author knew the result was true and did not repair in this little thing. Not a big deal. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, $\alpha\beta$ is optimal. To prove it, let $f,g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x^\alpha$ and $g(x)=x^\beta$.

Note that $f\circ g\in C^{\alpha\beta}$, however, for all $\gamma>\alpha\beta$, $f\circ g$ does not belong to $C^\gamma$.

Comment: Can something be said about local Hölder regularity?

Comment: @shuhalo Same thing, the example is only local Hölder here (or perhaps do you have a different locality def in mind).